# select active in menu using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this menu in wordpress, my problem is - I want that when I click on the page like agenda page the agenda menu will be class="currentpage". I'm not really familiar in wordpress in active menus. I added a code in functions.php here is my code -

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'currentpage';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Here is my html menu -

```
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/about/" class=""><span>about</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/agenda/" class=""><span>agenda</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/past-conferences/"  class=""><span>past conferences</span></a></li>
```

I want that to be inserted in class="currentpage"
How will I able to work on this thing?
Any help is muchly appreciated TIA.

Comment: hello, you add manually menu list?

Comment: yes i added manually

Answer (score 0):

If you want this function to work, you need to add your menu through Wordpress not manually.

At first, register `nav menu` in your themes functions.php file:

[Function Reference/register nav menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)

Example:

```
<?php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
}
?>
```

Then add your menu through Wordpress (Appearance > Menus).

After that replace your html menu with wp_nav_menu() function to display your custom menu.

[Navigation Menus Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)

Example:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Only after that your function will work as you expected.

Comment: then how will the nav menu like about pastconference venue menu will be rendered in html page? with this line of code?
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>

Comment: Yes, it will create all html for menu.

Comment: hi this seems when i added in functions.php 
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme-slug' ) );
}
wont working in appearance > menus

Comment: It won't appear on WP admin panel or something else is not working?